# Accessible Oracle-ADF - Pages - using wai-aria or other custom tags

Tags: accessibility, oracle-adf, wai-aria

As a newcomer to Oracle-ADF (late to the party, I know...):

I'd like to make an old ADF-project accessible for screenreader users.

Is it possible to enrich ADF-generated html with custom tags like those of WAI-ARIA (i.E. `aria-label="x",`role="navigation"` etc.? In case there are several strategies - is there a best practice?

Grateful for any advice,
MUBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26098_01/web.1112/e16181/af_access.htm#ADFUI12174) yet. ADF provides accessibility features by enabling  element in trinidad-config.xml.

Comment: Hello Srini, thank you for your reply! I did but unfortunately we're running an older version of ADF and the accessibility-mode ist not accessibile enough. We fixed the issue by overriding the renderer-kit. (We could have also overridden the renderer which would have been less error-prone, but that way was most cost-efficient.) Kind regards, Muba